# Haskell parsec space parsing errors

Tags: haskell, parsec

I have

```
stringparse = mstring
          <$> char '"'
          <*> (many alphaNum <|> many space)
          <*> char '"'
    where mstring a b c = [a] ++ b ++ [c]
```

When I do,

`parse stringparse "" "\"hello\"` I get `Right "\"hello\""`

When I do,

`parse stringparse "" "\"\""` I get `Right "\"\""`

But when I do,

`parse stringparse "" "\" \""` or `parse stringparse "" "\"he llo\""`

it does not work.

I get errors,

```
Left (line 1, column 2):
unexpected " "
expecting letter or digit or "\""
```

and

```
Left (line 1, column 4):
unexpected " "
expecting letter or digit or "\""
```

respectively.

I don't understand why the code does not parse spaces properly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because you're doing this `many alphaNum <|> many space`. `many` accepts 0 as an acceptable amount of characters, it always succeeds. This is the same behavior as `*` in regexs.

So in a `<|>` it's never going to fail and call the right side. So you're saying "try as many `alphaNum` as possible then take a `"`.

What you want is

```
many (alphaNum <|> space)
```

In other words, "as many `alphaNum`s or `space`s as possible".